# ResXexplor Dephi 2010 Demo

Tags: delphi, resources

Has anyone improved the ResXexplor demo that ships with Delphi 2010?

The demo does not load 256x256 icons. These icons appear as 0x0 0 colors.
The demo does not load Cursor Groups.
The bitdepths are not shown correctly except for for 16 color icons.  All other bitdepths are shown as:
 48x48 0 colors
 32x32 0 colors...
Any suggestions on how to fix these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but you might want to check out [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm). It's a free resource editor made in Delphi and comes with source code.

Comment: I tried for a long time with D2007 but did not suceed so Delphi 2010 will be even worse because of unitcode problems to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> The demo does not load 256x256 icons.

TIcon class in delphi does not support png-icons.

Comment: How about "The bitdepths are not shown correctly except for for 16 color icons."

Answer (score 0):

What about Res Editor by Melander?

http://melander.dk/reseditor/